# Is there any simple method to print stanford typed dependency object in its lemma form?

Tags: java, netbeans, dependencies, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

```
Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
      TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
      GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
      GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(tree);
      Collection<TypedDependency> td = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsedTree();
      System.out.println(td);
      Object[] list = td.toArray();
      TypedDependency typedDependency;
      for (Object object : list)
      {
        typedDependency = (TypedDependency) object;
        System.out.println(typedDependency.reln()+ " \t "+typedDependency.dep().word()+ " \t "+typedDependency.gov().word()+ " \n ");
      }
```

This is the code. Typed dependencies are generated correctly. Is there any way to print those typed dependency objects in its lemma form?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
typedDependency.dep().word()
```

to:

```
typedDependency.dep().lemma()
```

and you should get what you're after!